# Get user accessToken with thunkapi.getState()

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt

I want to send the user.accessToken together with my requests. The token is in my authSlice, and I want to bring it in my slices by using thunkapi.getState(). But when I send a reqest, I get the message, that there is no token.

That is out of my auth:

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
console.log(user);
```

Gives me back the accessToken.

That is the function in my slice:

```
export const updateMainNews = createAsyncThunk("mainNews/update", async (id, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{
        const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.accessToken;
        return await mainnewsService.updateMainNews(id, token);
    } catch(error){
        const message = (error.response 
            && error.response.data 
            && error.response.data.message) 
            || error.message 
            || error.toString();
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
})
```

That is my service:

```
const updateMainNews = async (mainNewsId, mainnewsData, token)=>{
    const config = {
            accessToken: token,
    }
    const response = await axios.put(API_URL + mainNewsId, mainnewsData, config);
    return response.data;
}
```

Tried now:

```
  headers:{
     token: token
}
```

But get the error:

```
 Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client
```

That is out of my verifytoken:

```
const verifyToken = (req,res,next)=>{
    const authHeader = req.headers.token;

    if(authHeader){

        const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];

        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SEC, (error, user)=>{
            if(error) res.status(403).json("Token ist nicht valide");

            req.user = user;
            next();
        })
    } else{
        res.status(403)
        throw new Error("Kein token vorhanden");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: @phry I have edited my post, it is the error 403 out of the else-statement. Means : "No token found". accesToken is the key in my user object

Comment: Sorry, typo, accessToken is the key in my user object.

Comment: Fixed the error by writing the following in my service:   const config = {
        header:{token: `Bearer ${token}`}
    }